# The CSV extension file - $_FILES not getting in server for large data like 2MB but for small KB size files its working

Tags: php, csv, file-upload

I am trying to parse a CSV file and upload the same to MySQL database. For small size files i am getting $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'] and everything works fine. But for a larger csv file having more records say having size 2.1 MB the result was:

```
Array
(
    [filename] => Array
        (
            [name] => GECT.csv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

What is issue as all code works for small sized files. When  i tried to print the $_FILES at the top i got this array with error 1. Anyone had this issue please suggest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default PHP limits the size of file uploads to 2M. This is set in the php.ini file setting [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize). You either need to change this value in the php.ini file or use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in your code.

```
// Set maximum upload size to 8M
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');
```

Keep in mind that if you are on shared hosting not all hosts allow you to use `ini_set()`.